# LoadTest fail due to "chmod(): Operation not permitted"

Tags: testing

I downloaded and installed a new Drupal 8 site via Composer.
I generated a new module using Drupal Console.
I tried running a phpUnit functional test of the newly generated module, and it keeps failing due to some folder permission:

> Exception: Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted
>   Drupal\Component\PhpStorage\FileStorage->createDirectory()() (Line: 168)

What grind my gears is that it was working OK a few days ago. Something is clearly wrong with my system, I just don't know what that is, or what changed since then.

I'm running a WSL with Apache 2.4.37 (PHP Version 7.2.12-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).

I have all the detailed steps to reproduce the case, my full *phpinfo*, and some more relevant information in [this gist I created](https://gist.github.com/zoiosilva/d1c0b7249a8191ce10f00d3bdd3954b3).

I spent the last few days browsing for a known solution, and some cases appear to be similar, but none of them seems to hit the spot.

I am using Windows 10.0.17134.407; the tests from the browser are passing. All the files and folders on the project are owned by 'zoio' (user and group); the file permissions for folders and files in modules, sites/default/files, and sites/simpletest are set to 0777.

I tried to follow the tips on [this WSL issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3172), but I just ended up with a different failure, still related to permission and ownership.

> Drupal\Tests\sandbox\Functional\LoadTest::testLoad()
>   Exception: User warning: mkdir(): Permission Denied
>   Drupal\Component\PhpStorage\FileStorage->createDirectory()() (Line: 174)
>    /mnt/c/www/temp/d8_temp/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Test/HttpClientMiddleware/TestHttpClientMiddleware.php:51 (...) /mnt/c/www/temp/d8_temp/web/modules/custom/sandbox/tests/src/Functional/LoadTest.php:33
>   ERRORS!
>   Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Errors: 1.

Comment: Hey Zoio, this sounds very similar to https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3172, is that one of the cases you came across? Did you run any Windows updates before the problem appeared?

Comment: I haven't come across this one, but I tried it now. Still no success. No Windows Update runned recently. I also updated the post with more info based on your tips. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Ur welcome. Did you try running the tests from the browser?

Comment: The tests from the browser are passing, though. This is very intriguing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, the `chmod` wasn't really working.

It was an issue with the mounted drivers in the WSL Ubuntu installation. Based on [Stefanos Petrakis' comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273287/phpunit-loadtest-fail-due-to-chmod-operation-not-permitted#comment337119_273287), simply trying to unmount and mount the driver with the proper options enabled wouldn't solve the issue by itself. What solved was a bit more drastic:

1. Factory reset the ubuntu ([how-to](https://medium.com/@gauravnelson/how-to-reset-ubuntu-in-wsl-f64dd7977e73));
2. re-mount the driver, with the metadata option included ([source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/01/12/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/)):

   sudo umount /mnt/c
   sudo mount -t drvfs C: /mnt/c -o metadata,uid=1000,gid=1000
3. Install php, Apache, and everything.

Only then, the phpunit tests did work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the user **zoio** (the user you're running `vendor/bin/phpunit` as) doesn't have write permissions on your module folder.

Can you tell your module folder's owner and group?

If **zoio** isn't the owner and neither of its groups are assigned to this folder, then your script really won't be able to `chmod` it or modify its contents.

You need to grant write permissions to either the owner or the group.

As a quick and dirty test, you can try running `chmod -R 777 path_to_your_module_folder`.

Just remember to adjust folder permissions back once you've figured out the problem.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I updated the post with more info related to your answer. All project's folders and files are owned by zoio:zoio (user and group). Still, I runned the chmod recursively as you recommended, just to be sure. Still no success.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this run would be by using `sudo` and the same user as the one running apache (that would be [www-data according to your gist](https://gist.github.com/zoiosilva/d1c0b7249a8191ce10f00d3bdd3954b3#file-phpinfo-txt-L36)):

```
sudo -u www-data vendor/bin/phpunit -c ./web/core/ \
  ./web/modules/custom/sandbox/tests/src/Functional/LoadTest.php
```

Good luck!

P.S.: (inspired from https://serverfault.com/a/453823)

Comment: I just tried it. Still no success: `chmod(): Operation not permitted`.